# Get matched region for a number in python's phonenumbers library

Tags: python, phone-number, libphonenumber, phonenumberutils

I am using python's [phonenumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers) library to parse and validate numbers like this:

```
>> import phonenumbers
>>> x = phonenumbers.parse("+442083661177")
>>> print x
Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
```

And wanted to know that if there is any possible way to get the matched the 2-letter **Region** for given number for further use?

I have tried this method, which is mentioned in Readme:

```
>>> from phonenumbers import timezone
>>> gb_number = phonenumbers.parse("+447986123456")
>>> list(timezone.time_zones_for_number(gb_number))
['Europe/London']
```

But the problem is I can not find a way to parse another number using these timezones. (`phonenumbers.parse("07986123456", 'Europe/London')` will throw an exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the **country code** first rather than the timezone:

```
>>> gb_number = phonenumbers.parse("+447986123456")
>>> cc = phonenumbers.region_code_for_number(gb_number)
>>> cc
'GB'
>>> phonenumbers.parse("07986123456", cc)
PhoneNumber(country_code=44, national_number=7986123456, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=None, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
```

This is because many countries have different dial codes but the same time-zone.